# 5 divs, same class, show one - hide the others (not siblings)

Tags: jquery, class

I have 5 divs with the class "rocksMenu_zoomContainer" (not siblings). I'm using the following code:

```
function zoomContainers_showHide(){
if(menuItem_place === 0){
  $("#granitos_zoomContainer").show();
}
else if(menuItem_place === 1){
  $("#marmores_zoomContainer").show();
}
else if(menuItem_place === 2){
  $("#calcarios_zoomContainer").show();
}
else if(menuItem_place === 3){
  $("#compositos_zoomContainer").show();
}
else if(menuItem_place === 4){
  $("#ardosias_zoomContainer").show();
}
```

}

This function **zoomContainers_showHide()** is executed in a click (button).

This works fine, the problem is following the rule of **one always visible, all others always hidden**.

HTML markup:

```
<!-- Granitos -->

          <div id="rocksMenu_granitos" class="menuItem">
            <div id="granitos_zoomContainer" class="rocksMenu_zoomContainer"></div>
            <div id="rocksMenu_granitos_subContainer" class="menuItem_subContainer">
              <img id="granitos" class="rocksMenu_image" src="images/rocksMenu_granitos.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div> <!-- End of id="rocksMenu_granitos" -->

<!-- Mármores -->

          <div id="rocksMenu_marmores" class="menuItem">
            <div id="marmores_zoomContainer" class="rocksMenu_zoomContainer"></div>
            <div id="rocksMenu_marmores_subContainer" class="menuItem_subContainer">
              <img id="marmores" class="rocksMenu_image" src="images/rocksMenu_marmores.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div> <!-- End of id="rocksMenu_marmores" -->

<!-- Calcários -->

          <div id="rocksMenu_calcarios" class="menuItem">
            <div id="calcarios_zoomContainer" class="rocksMenu_zoomContainer"></div>
            <div id="rocksMenu_calcarios_subContainer" class="menuItem_subContainer">
              <img id="calcarios" class="rocksMenu_image" src="images/rocksMenu_calcarios.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div> <!-- End of id="rocksMenu_calcarios" -->

<!-- Compósitos -->

          <div id="rocksMenu_compositos" class="menuItem">
            <div id="compositos_zoomContainer" class="rocksMenu_zoomContainer"></div>
            <div id="rocksMenu_compositos_subContainer" class="menuItem_subContainer">
              <img id="compositos" class="rocksMenu_image" src="images/rocksMenu_compositos.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div> <!-- End of id="rocksMenu_compositos" -->

<!-- Ardósias -->

          <div id="rocksMenu_ardosias" class="menuItem">
            <div id="ardosias_zoomContainer" class="rocksMenu_zoomContainer"></div>
            <div id="rocksMenu_ardosias_subContainer" class="menuItem_subContainer">
              <img id="ardosias" class="rocksMenu_image" src="images/rocksMenu_ardosias.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div> <!-- End of id="rocksMenu_compositos" -->
```

I click the button, it shows the corresponding  div but all the others remain visible. I can't figure this one out - I would use the siblings(), but they're not siblings...

Pedro

Comment: And what's the ([sscce](http://sscce.org/)/relevant) HTML? Can we have a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to see it in action? Help us to help you, and you'll get better answers! And what's `menuItem_place`?

Comment: _This works fine_ Off course not, `hasClass` returns a boolean value, your code should throw an error.

Comment: Sorry... I didn't have the hasClass on my 1st try.... edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work

```
function zoomContainers_showHide(){
$(".rocksMenu_zoomContainer:visible").hide();
$(".rocksMenu_zoomContainer").eq(menuItem_place).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will hide all menus, then show the one at menuItem_place:

```
function zoomContainers_showHide(){    
    $(".rocksMenu_zoomContainer").hide();
    $(".rocksMenu_zoomContainer:eq(" + menuItem_place +")").show();
}
```

Comment: You need to terminate your second string.

Comment: problem in concatenation in `:eq`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just hide *all* of them, and then show the one you want to show? It will all be too fast for the user to see the difference anyway...

```
function showZoomContainer(id) {
    $('.menuItem').hide(); // use slide-up or whatever if you need something else.
                           // it won't matter for already hidden divs
    $('#' + id).show(); // or slide-down, or watever
}
```

Use like so:

```
// show compositos, hide all others:
showZoomContainer('rocksMenu_compositos');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
function zoomContainers_showHide(){
   $(".rocksMenu_zoomContainer:visible").hide();
   $(".rocksMenu_zoomContainer").eq(menuItem_place).show();
}
```

Comment: And the same here.. thank you. I'd give a green check mark to all of you guys.